# How to check all checkbox for entire column of months in single row?

Tags: javascript

I have an page with multiple checkboxes.

Each record I embedded checkboxes for months and CHECK ALL button at the end. When I select this button, all checkboxes of all months of specific record must be selected. How can I do this?

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVYuV.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, because it makes it harder to debug the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_all').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
             $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
    $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
        if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
        }else{
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- check box value for input -->
1<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value=""/>
2<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value=""/>
3<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value=""/>
4<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value=""/>
<br><br>
<!-- check box for check all -->
<span>select all:</span>
<input type="checkbox" id="select_all" />
```